# Working with HTML Entities

Tags: php, html

I am storing HTML code in my MySQL table column. For inserting records, I framed the query like this:

```
$InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO listing (ldate, places, company, designation, projectdetails, desiredcandidate, hrname, hrcontact, email) VALUES (DATE_FORMAT('" .$ldate ."','%Y/%m/%d'),'" .$places. "','" .$company. "','" .$designation. "','" .htmlentities($projectdetails). "','" .htmlentities($desiredcandidate). "','" .$hrname. "','" .$hrcontact. "','" .$email. "')";
```

But when I am output the results using following code, it shows the text with HTML tags. It is not implementing the tags on the page.

```
$FetchResultsQuery = "SELECT * FROM listing WHERE recordid=" . $SelectedRowID;

    $result = mysql_query($FetchResultsQuery);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    if ($row)
    {
        $PostedDate = date($row[0],'d.m.Y');
        $Places =  $row[1];
        $Company = $row[2];
        $Designation = $row[3];
        $ProjectDetails = $row[4];
        $DesiredCandidate = $row[5];
        $HRName = $row[6];
        $HRContact = $row[7];
        $Email = $row[8];
    }

       <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px; text-align:justify;"><h4>&nbsp;</h4>
          <p><strong>Company Name: </strong> <strong><?PHP echo $Company; ?></strong></p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><strong>Location: </strong> <?PHP echo $Places; ?> </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><strong>Posted Date: </strong><span class="style19"> <?PHP echo $PostedDate; ?></span></p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><strong>Designation:</strong><?PHP echo $Designation; ?></p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><strong>Project Details :</strong></p><br>
              <?PHP echo $ProjectDetails; ?>    
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><strong>HR Name: </strong> <?PHP echo $HRName; ?> </p>
          <p>&nbsp; </p>
          <p><strong> HR's Contact details: </strong><?PHP echo $HRContact;  ?></p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><strong>Email: </strong><?PHP echo $Email;  ?></p>
          <p><span class="style18"><strong><br />
            <br />
          </strong></span></p></td>
        <td></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to echo like this:

```
print html_entity_decode('your text here');
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function converts all your angle brackets to their HTML entity equivalent. So instead of outputting '<' you will just get '&lt;'.

When storing data in the database, more often than not you will want to store it in it's raw format i.e. un-encoded, as you might not always want to display the data in HTML e.g. you might want to export it to CSV. You would typically use **htmlentities** when outputting the data in the browser.

If you haven't done so already - it's a bit hard to tell from your INSERT code snippet - you might want to modify your SQL to pass your parameters through the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: +1 putting HTML in the database is almost always totally the wrong thing, and certainly is not a security measure to speak of. Keep text raw and encode it as the final step on the way out to the page, like `Company: <?php echo(htmlspecialchars($result['company'])); ?>` (or shortcut function to take the typing out of it).